How can I enforce that a class passed to a template satisfies the rule of 3 (or 0, or 5)?
Context
This context is just to explain how we got the problem, you can just skip to the "Problem" section if you want.
In our company we recently had some non-reproducible crashes. After some investigation, we discovered that our vector implementation used qsort as the default sort method.
The crash occurred because qsort has undefined behavior for non-trivially movable classes.
We changed our code to keep qsort for the classes that are trivially movable, std::sort for those that are move constructible and move assignable, and not allow sorting for the other classes.
We then ran into other crashes because some classes were move constructible and move assignable, but did not satisfy the rule of three.
Luckily, it worked before because memory was just being moved, but now that the auto-generated move constructor is called, it causes problems.
Here is an example of code that works fine when data is just moved, but results in a double delete when the move constructor is called:
struct MyStruct {
    int* myPointer;

    MyStruct()
    {
        myPointer = new int;
    }

    ~MyStruct()
    {
        delete myPointer;
    }
}

This class is badly written, and that is the main problem, but since we are changing the previous behavior and have a code base of several thousand files, we cannot afford to check all calls to sort.
Which brings us to our problem.
Problem
How can we check that the classes we call our sort on satisfy the rule of 3 (or 0 or 5) and thus will work properly?
We tried to check if the class is move constructible and move assignable, but that is not enough.
In the example struct above, for example, the following static asserts will pass.
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<MyStruct>::value)
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable<MyStruct>::value)

While the custom destructor will prevent the move constructor from being implicitly generated, the copy constructor will still be. And if the copy constructor is defined, the class is move constructible.

I would use std::sort for everything. As for automatically testing the classes, this most probably isn't possible (without some sort of a static analyzer; maybe clang-tidy has something?).

You could also write unit tests that test each of your class types to make sure they have the correct behavior instead of just the correct signatures.

You could do a static_assert for the class having a move constructor.  (I suspect the same technique might be able to be used for move assignment.)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912859/4641116

"check that the classes we call our sort on satisfy the rule of 3 (or 0 or 5) and thus will work properly?" -- Satisfying the rule does not imply that a class will work properly. There is a significant difference between implementing a move constructor and implementing a bug-free move constructor.

Rule 0 is the default. Rule 5 is optimization. Rule 3 can be enforced via CRTP. But if you need pointers, use std::unique_ptr; it is move-only with correct destructor. Now you can define copy operations if needed, and move operations for optimization. If you don't use pointers, you won't need to worry about rule 350(for the most part).

@HolyBlackCat Thank you for your suggestion of using clang-tidy, it seems that cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions is the appropriate rule.
@n.m.couldbeanAI The code base is very old (2007) and we cannot garantee that all the code went through a code review.
@JaMiT I agree with you, but checking this case will drastically reduce errors, even if they could still exist.

@Eljay This kind of trick could do the job but we are unfortunately using MSVC

Fortunately, the trick works with the latest Visual Studio and /std:c++20.

Make sure you replace all uses of qsort from the codebase with std::sort as qsort is much slower than std::sort

A class can satisfy a "Rule of X" and still be implemented wrong.
For example, a class that owns an outside resource (via a pointer, a handle, etc) can let the compiler implicitly define the copy/move constructors and/or copy/move assignment operators, and  they will mismanage that resource. The class would need to implement them manually to manage the resource correctly.
That is why the Rule's exist in the first place. And while you can validate whether the constructors and operators exist at compile-time, you can't validate their runtime behavior at compile-time. That is what static analyzers and unit tests are meant for.

I agree with you, but checking that a class satisfies rule of X will drastically reduce errors, even if they could still exist.
